# What is a Transfer Function to the System? State Characteristics or State Properties

Tags: terminology

GIVEN: in linear 1DOF mechanics / vibrations processes, ones that characterize a system’s state variables (position u & velocity du_dt) as effected by a causing force f.

Simply: $f= m\cdot {ddu}_{ddt} + c\cdot {du}_{dt} + k\cdot u$
where m=mass, damping=c, k=stiffness are STATE PROPERTIES, d(du/dt)/dt=acceleration, du/dt=velocity, position (really displacement)=u are STATE CHARACTERISTICS

KNOWING: that that system’s transfer function equation has STATE-PROPERTY coefficients of mass, stiffness and damping onto the STATE-CHARACTERS of acceleration, displacement and velocity.

FURTHER KNOWING: that these STATE-PROPERTIES’ coefficients, say for example Stiffness, is just a representation of it’s constitutive equations for elasticity which is the 1D relationship between stress and strain. That is a STATE-PROPERTY, the equation and the terms and the things that they represent.

IT IS POSTULATED: that these constitutive equations are that system’s state’s “CAUSAL CAPACITY” equations. Here:

NOTE: I think I have seen them called Structural Equation Models (SEM) in data science or economics or soft sciences or causal skeletons in medicine. BUT not strictly civil or mechanical engineering terms.

QUESTION: If constitutive equations (causal capacities) are STATE-PROPERTIES then why are transfer functions considered STATE-CHARACTERIZATIONS?

MY ANSWER: transfer functions are characterizations because they are class / type of functions, but then become a property when being an studied as an object for specific case (INSTANCED).

Comment: had a really hard time interpreting your formulas. I've tried to put them into latex, can you polease check whether they say what you intended to say?

Comment: Would they then be in general terms class methods (or instance methods if unique to each instance)? They are functional in creating an output for a given input but also stateful based on prior inputs.

Comment: @Marcus thanks. Try this is link here shows an equivalent form: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass-spring-damper_model

Comment: The form there uses completely different symbols. I can't extrapolate what **you** meant here. Seriously, can you say whether the formula as I converted it makes sense, and then *define* all your symbols?

Comment: I'm not getting sense out of the math either.  Could you at least choose Newtonian or Leibniz notation (i.e., $du/dt$ or $\dot u$) to denote a derivative, and _be consistent_?  Then define each variable (i.e. "$f(t) = a x(t) + b$, where $x(t)$ is the input signal and $a$ and $b$ are system characteristics)").  Basically like you'd see in a paper or a book **which are all done the same way for a reason**.

Comment: Ok sorry about the notation differences. So I defined the terms in the equation, but didn’t get anywhere with the mathjax yet. But the equation you have up there Marcus is not correct.